# Input data error in Tensorflow based transformer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I was making a custom transformer model based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#setup_input_pipeline) tutorial for my dataset. 
The overall shape of the dataset is like : 
**Encoder input** : frame features of (Batch size, 150, 1024) 
**Decoder input** : word sequence of (Batch size, 50), composed with [sos token, integer tokens]
**Decoder output** : word sequence of (Batch size, 50), composed with [integer tokens, eos token]
And each of them are named as "encoder_ipt_train", "decoder_ipt_train", "decoder_opt_train".
Here i used the code below for 
**1. Generating dataset batches**

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
BUFFER_SIZE = 16384

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
{
    'inputs': encoder_ipt_train,
    'dec_inputs': decoder_ipt_train 
},
{
    'outputs': decoder_opt_train 
},
))

dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

**2. In the training phase**

```
EPOCHS = 20

train_step_signature = [
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
]


@tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
def train_step(enc_ipt, dec_ipt, dec_opt):

    enc_padding_mask, combined_mask, dec_padding_mask = create_masks(enc_ipt, dec_ipt)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions, _ = transformer(enc_ipt, dec_ipt, True,
                                     enc_padding_mask, combined_mask, dec_padding_mask)
        loss = loss_function(dec_opt, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(accuracy_function(dec_opt, predictions))


for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()

    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()

    for (batch, (inp, tar)) in enumerate(dataset):
        case 1 --> train_step(inp, tar)
        case 2 --> train_step(inp['inputs'],inp['dec_inputs'], tar['outputs'])

        if batch % 50 == 0:
          print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} Batch {batch} Loss {train_loss.result():.4f} Accuracy {train_accuracy.result():.4f}')

    if (epoch + 1) % 5 == 0:
        ckpt_save_path = ckpt_manager.save()
        print(f'Saving checkpoint for epoch {epoch+1} at {ckpt_save_path}')

    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} Loss {train_loss.result():.4f} Accuracy {train_accuracy.result():.4f}')

    print(f'Time taken for 1 epoch: {time.time() - start:.2f} secs\n')
```

But this results a error like this, whether i use **case 1** or **case 2** in **2.** :
[The entire error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQUO4.png)

```
TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.
```

Now i'm doubting about my pipeline structure or the data type, but i have no idea how to change data type from 'dataset' in **1**. Is there anyone who had similar problems like this or solved it?
and some additional questions : 
First, I wonder if I'm using the tf.data.Dataset package in a right way. As far as i know, 'dataset' in **1** returns a dictionary of tensor batches, such that if i run the code below,

```
for (batch, (dict_1, dict_2)) in enumerate(dataset):
```

**dict_1['inputs']** returns the batch of **encoder_ipt_train** with size of (32, 150, 1024). I wonder whether my understanding is correct.

Second, is there a better way(or a right way)to insert data batches to my training_step() function?

Sincerely, Seunghoon.